# CNN - RNN model data preparation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have a dataset that has images for 2000,2010 and 2020. I wrote them in 3 different tfrecord files named combined_2000.tfrecord, combined_2010.tfrecord and combined_2020.tfrecord. I want to use a CNN - LSTM architecture for a regression model on this. the image size is 40X40X7 and the tfrecord files have images and labels. I did some data preparation as follows:# Split each year's dataset into train, validation, and test sets

```
train_size = int(0.7 * 2000)
val_size = int(0.15 * 2000)
test_size = 2000 - train_size - val_size

train_tf_2000 = combined_dataset_2000.take(train_size)
remaining_tf_2000 = combined_dataset_2000.skip(train_size)
val_tf_2000 = remaining_tf_2000.take(val_size)
test_tf_2000 = remaining_tf_2000.skip(val_size)

train_tf_2010 = combined_dataset_2010.take(train_size)
remaining_tf_2010 = combined_dataset_2010.skip(train_size)
val_tf_2010 = remaining_tf_2010.take(val_size)
test_tf_2010 = remaining_tf_2010.skip(val_size)

train_tf_2020 = combined_dataset_2020.take(train_size)
remaining_tf_2020 = combined_dataset_2020.skip(train_size)
val_tf_2020 = remaining_tf_2020.take(val_size)
test_tf_2020 = remaining_tf_2020.skip(val_size)
```

The model is defined as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, TimeDistributed, LSTM, Dense, Dropout

# Assuming your image dimensions are (image_height, image_width, num_channels)
input_shape = (40, 40, 7)  # Adjust num_channels if needed
num_years = 3


# Define CNN model
cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
cnn.add(Flatten())

# Define LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn, input_shape=(num_years, *input_shape)))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))  # Single output unit for regression

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae'])
```

I am not sure how to feed the images into the model. I have one image per year and each of the years has 2000 images. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/tfrecord/

Comment: You combine all train_* images into one array with their corresponding labels, and then combine all val_* images into one array. In the fit() you pass these two arrays.

Comment: Do i need to create a seqeunce?